# Volley error in android studio emulator but works smoothly in real phone

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-volley

I can use the emulator to access the internet, such as google maps, browser etc, but Volley doesn't work. Yet the same app works fine in a real phone. Is there a configure in emulator we need to mind, please? Thanks.

Comment: Try to see logcat to detect root cause of the issue. Maybe your emulation does not connect to Internet, etc.

Comment: Thank you Son Truong. I am new in Android Studio, I have to say the logcat is quite frustrating...finally I locate 'Cleartext HTTP traffic to dummy.restapiexample.com not permitted'.

Answer (score 1):

The real phone is on a lower version of Android, which supports cleartext.
Starting with Android 9.0 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default.
I added a line to Manifest and that is it.

```
<application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ...>
    ...
</application>
```

Comment: Does that mean if the data being sent was encrypted, it would not count as clear text traffic?